# Binning pandas/numpy array/dataframe of zscores

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, binning

I have a pandas dataframe of Z-scores. So, negative and positive np.float64's. I've removed all [-1.0, 1.0] values, so an example would be as follows:

`REF          ?|100133144  ?|100134869  ?|10357  ?|10431
A41B-07        0.000          0.0      0.0    1.010
A41B-07        1.497          0.0      0.0   -1.139
A41B-07        0.000          0.0      0.0    1.492
A41B-07        2.300          0.0      0.0    1.310
A41B-07        0.000          0.0      0.0   -1.262
A41B-07        0.000          0.0      0.0    1.283
A41B-07       -1.396          0.0      0.0    1.409
A41B-07       -1.243          0.0      0.0   -1.509
A144-07        0.000          0.0      0.0    1.200
A115-07        0.000          0.0      0.0    1.359`

I want to discretize these values in order to run LDA, so I need integers. Bin the positive z scores above +1.0 into 10 bins, on a per column basis. Then same for negatives below -1.0. So, for each column, the bin range is the max z to min z. Evenly slice that into 10 bins. Note these are separate ranges and thus different bins for positive and negatives within the same column. The 0.0 values are left alone. Since bin numbers are positive, both positive and negative sides will map to positive integers. So you'd expect something like the following. Note that I just typed in ints, these are just for demonstration.

`REF          ?|100133144  ?|100134869  ?|10357  ?|10431
A41B-07        0.000          0.0      0.0        1
A41B-07            1          0.0      0.0        1
A41B-07        0.000          0.0      0.0       10
A41B-07           10          0.0      0.0        6
A41B-07        0.000          0.0      0.0        3
A41B-07        0.000          0.0      0.0        2
A41B-07           10          0.0      0.0        8
A41B-07            1          0.0      0.0       10
A144-07        0.000          0.0      0.0        2
A115-07        0.000          0.0      0.0        3`

Here is my extremely ugly attempt. It doesn't run. I've been playing with this for over 15h and am at my wits end on making anything work.

```
for gene in data:
    max_pos = data[data >= 0.0][gene].max(skipna=True)
    min_pos = data[data >= 1.0][gene].min(skipna=True)
    max_neg = data[data <= -1.0][gene].min(skipna=True)
    min_neg = data[data <= -1.0][gene].max(skipna=True)
    pos_bins = neg_bins = []
    pos = False
    neg = False

    if (max_pos != min_pos) and (not math.isnan(max_pos)) and (not math.isnan(min_pos)):
        pos_bins = np.linspace(min_pos, max_pos, num=10, endpoint=False)
        pos = True
    if (max_neg != min_neg) and (not math.isnan(min_neg)) and (not math.isnan(min_neg)):
        neg_bins = np.linspace(min_neg, max_neg, num=10, endpoint=False)
        neg = True

    if pos:
        data[gene] = pd.np.digitize(data[data >= +1.0][gene], pos_bins, right=True)
    if neg:
        data[gene] = pd.np.digitize(data[data <= -1.0][gene], neg_bins, right=True)
```

Any pointers would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: To make sure I understand, is this a good paraphrasing of your request? For each column: for positive and negative z-scores **separately**: bin the absolute value of each z-score into 10 equal-width bins, then output the index (starting from 1) of the bin that each score falls into.

Comment: Yea, that's actually quite a good paraphrase. I figured out a working, though likely not idea solution, below.

Answer (score 0):

Friend ended up offering an idea which led to this solution

```
def binx(x, max_pos, min_pos, max_neg, min_neg):
    if x >= 1.0:
        if x == min_pos:
            return 1.0
        elif x == max_pos:
            return 10.0
        else:
            return ((x - min_pos) / (max_pos - min_pos) * 10) + 1
    elif x <= -1.0:
        if x == min_neg:
            return 1.0
        elif x == max_neg:
            return 10.0
        else:
            return ((x - min_neg) / (max_neg - min_neg) * 10) + 1
    else:
        return x
...
...
...
for gene in data:
    max_pos = data[data >= 1.0][gene].max(skipna=True)
    min_pos = data[data >= 1.0][gene].min(skipna=True)
    max_neg = data[data <= -1.0][gene].min(skipna=True)
    min_neg = data[data <= -1.0][gene].max(skipna=True)

    data[gene] = data[gene].apply(lambda x: binx(x, max_pos, min_pos, max_neg, min_neg))
    data = data.astype(np.int64)
```